# array parameters pointer error?

Tags: c, arrays

So this function just makes a swap between arrays. `r` is the length of the array `i` and `l` are the index to change. it gives me an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1)`.

```
void swap(int a[], int first, int second, int r) {
    int tempp = a[first];
    a[first] = a[second];
    a[second] = tempp;
}
```

This function generates the permutations for the Array.

```
void permute(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int temp[r];

    int i;
    if (l == r)
        for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
            printf("%d\n", a[k]);
        }
    else {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap(a[r], l, i, r);
            permute(a[r], l + 1, r);
            swap(a[r], l, i, r);
        }
    }
}
```

so functions takes in inputs from the main and makes an array based on some requirements.

```
void perm_rec_1(int N, int nr_vals) {
    int a[N], temp = nr_vals - 1;
    int output[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (i >= nr_vals) {
            a[i] = temp;
            continue;
        } else {
            a[i] = i;
        }
    }
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    permute(a[N], 0, (nr_vals) - 1);
}
```

Comment: @M.M Where is oid?

Comment: `swap(a[r]` should give a compiler message.  `a[r]` is an `int`, however the first parameter of the function is `int[]` .  Pay attention to what the compiler says about your code, and fix anything mentioned in messages.

Comment: @M.M Thats void just forgot a letter.

Comment: `permute(a[N]` has a similar error.

Comment: The permute function declares variable `temp` and never uses it, which suggests a logic error

Comment: @M.M it says incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing int to parameter of type int* .

Comment: Yes, you need to fix this before trying to run your code.

Comment: @M.M its one of the errors that i couldn't figure out as well.

Comment: Your question should be asking about that; any runtime errors are irrelevant

Comment: i think even after solving it the error mentioned in the question would still be the same. if i convert it to pass a pointer (&a...) the same error will be given. @M.M

Comment: `&a` would be the wrong type of pointer . maybe you meant `a`

Comment: Yes exactly. sorry been working on these code for a while @M.M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working through the various type errors in the code, the following compiles and runs:

```
void swap(int a[], int first, int second) {
    int temporary = a[first];
    a[first] = a[second];
    a[second] = temporary;
}

void permute(int a[], int l, int r) {
    if (l == r) {
        for (int k = 0; k < r; k++) {
            printf("%d\n", a[k]);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap(a, l, i);
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap(a, l, i);
        }
    }
}

void perm_rec_1(int N, int nr_vals) {
    int a[N], temp = nr_vals - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (i >= nr_vals) {
            a[i] = temp;
        } else {
            a[i] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    permute(a, 0, (nr_vals) - 1);
}
```

Though I can't say any of it beyond `swap()` works as I'm not certain what it's trying to do.